# have any related accounts disappeared?

Tags: discussion

I thought I had a related account on the other
SO sites but my only related account appears
to be here in meta.SO.

Have any accounts been lost?

If yes, how do we restart and connect ...
I'm sure I've screwed up the process
because now I have a severfault
account of https://serverfault.com/users/51718/user51718
created today that I would rather connect as
../gerrylowry instead.

I'm assuming you do not blow away
occassional visitors.

thnx/g.

edit:  connecting my meta SO and SO openid to my serverfault account allows me to link all 3 accounts.  Bonus:  for linking meta SO and SO to my serverfault I got 100 (decimal) bonus points at serverfault.  Thank you Jeff et al.  2010-09-14

Comment: Your OpenID should be listed on your profile. Does the one on the Server Fault profile match the one that is on your Stack Overflow profile? If not, the auto-association won't work.

Comment: And yes, users who do not visit for long periods of time are assumed to have left the site. Don't remember offhand how long a period is required, but I think it was six months or so. Ah, here it is: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: {is 'm' for mike, like our famous canadian austin powers?} thank you mmyers ... sorry i took so long to get back here ... alligators in my swap and a near death in the family kept me away ... my meta SO and my SO openid are not the same but somehow i managed to connect the two accounts way back when AFAIK ... they have in common the same gmail account so it's strange the openids are not 100% identical ... my big mistake was using a different gmail openid at serverfault ... thnx for pointing me in the right direction and thnx for the link about "abandoned accounts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmyers comments lead me to notice my openids are different (nearly the same at SO and meta SO but different at serverfault).

i forgot my authentication at SO, meta SO, and serverfault ... by asking for help, the SO help me remember system showed me the error i made at serverfault.

while i checking this as the answer, the credit really should go to mmyers who was the catalyst.